# How to count the offset of different data type in struct?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I know that different data type will align. But I can't figure out why the size of this structure is 12.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct ABC {
    char a; 
    char b; 
    int k;  
    char c; 
};

int main()
{
    struct ABC a;
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(a)); //12
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look into [offsetof()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).

Comment: Different compilers will produce different results, so without knowing what compiler you're using, it's hard to answer. Just guessing, it looks like it's committing a 32-bit value for the first 2 characters, another 32-bit value for the int, and a third 32-bit value for the final char. You could experiment a little, by creating an array of this struct, and printing the size of the array.

Comment: How big do you *think* it should be? ***Why?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it works like this

Here are the rules:

`char`s are aligned to 1 byte

`int`s are aligned to 4 bytes

The entirety of the struct must be aligned to a multiple of the largest element.

the final struct will be

```
struct ABC
{
    char a; // Byte 0
    char b; // Byte 1
    char padding0[2]; // to align the int to 4 bytes
    int k;  // Byte 4
    char c; // Byte 8
    char padding1[3]; // align the structure to the multiple of largest element.
    // largest element is int with 4 bytes, the closest multiple is 12, so pad 3 bytes more.
}
```

Comment: @abelenky whoops. fixed it